# git, how to reference last commit in current branch

Tags: git

While writing code i like to commit at stages where some progress has been made, as i use cli for git i have to type same commit message again and again using -m option.

reading git documentation there is -C option for commit which can reuse message from specific commit.

**Is there any easy way to refer last commit in working branch?**

**git commit -C :LastCommit(Something like this possible?)**

Comment: Reason i have asked this because in some cases i just commit often so i can compare what changed while i am working on. And this is just a use case i was interested in knowing. I agree with lot of comments regarding not repeating messages but i can say i want to do it for some special use cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HEAD references the last commit. But honestly your question is strange since using the last commit message should be exceptional...

Comment: I guess, he just has some use for it... Just tested that `git commit -C HEAD` works as intended.

Comment: Hm, maybe one could actually make a whole library of "fake commits" just for the purpose of having "canned messages" that one could use, maybe rather with `git commit -c` than `git commit -C`. I think, it wouldn't matter on which branch they are, so one could put all of them into a "canned_messages" branch.

Comment: @Tilman weird propgramming practise, but everything can be imagined... Wouldn't work with such a guy who don't put contextualized commit messages

Comment: Well, I am actually using git for managing checkouts from yet another version control system and whenever I do an update from the other system and check that into git, I will have an "update from blabla mainline" commit... So, this is a case where commit messages are not really documenting the changes but rather the workflow. I would then work on my git repo and later check-in from that working dir to the remote non-git system.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just adding work to the last commit, use the `--amend` option.

You can use something like the snipets provided by alxp, but I would suggest tweaking them to use the `--oneline` param, since that would work multiline git commit messages.

Answer (score 0):

To just grab the last commit message you can do

```
git log -1 |tail -n 1
```

so a commit would insert that inline, like

```
git commit -m "`git log -1 |tail -n 1`"
```

That said, I think it would be better practice to not repeat a commit message, and if you are just committing a non-standalone change to combine those commits into one once your work is done. See [here](http://www.gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html) for how to squash commits.